# Rename files from their content

Tags: rename, batch-rename

I have thousands of txt files with a .pdbqt extension in a directory named `100000cpds_ligand_00001.pdbqt`, `100000cpds_ligand_00002.pdbqt`, `100000cpds_ligand_*****.pdbqt` and would like to rename them according to a unique identifier from their contents.

The identifier is given as `REMARK  Name = PV-000009607404` in a single line, where `PV-000009607404` can be of variable length, text, and numbers (e.g. `ZINC001248485427`, etc.). I would like to only keep the identifier part in the file name and not the `REMARK Name =` part. So, I would e.g. change `100000cpds_ligand_00001.pdbqt` to `PV-000009607404.pdbqt`. I can do it from the command line, but lprefarably I would like to use a small script.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done an example which should only copy files instead of rename. Comments indicate some of the logic. I'm not a bash expert, but I tested this on a file.

You should create this file in the same directory as your source files, and name it something like `pdbqt-mover.sh`.

Either call it by typing `bash pdbqt-mover.sh` or you'll have to set permissions on the file so you can execute it using `./pdbqt-mover.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# process only files starting with 100000cpds_ligand_ and ending in .pdbqt
for infile in 100000cpds_ligand_*.pdbqt; do

  # get the pv-* string from lines beginning with "REMARK  Name = "
  # get the group matching PV-**** up to the end of the line
  pvnum=$(sed -n 's/^REMARK  Name = \(PV-\S*\)/\1/p' "$infile")

  # construct the output filename
  outfile="$pvnum".pdbqt

  # only copy if the output file doesn't exist
  if [ ! -f $outfile ] ; then
    # cp instead of mv
    cp "$infile" "$outfile"
    echo "Copied $infile to $outfile"
  else
    echo "File $outfile exists! Skipping"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, you should add your command line work to your question to show what you've tried and how it is working for you. Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This is  very easily done using grep and also a terminal file browser called RANGER.
First use grep to pull out the lines containing filenames. For example

```
grep REMARK * > fnlist
```

edit fnlist and get rid of the redundant string of "REMARK NAME = ". You now have a clean list of new file names.

Launch Ranger, navigate to the directory containing your files and do a bulkrename operation. Paste the contents of nflist when presented and you are done.